# Killing thread/process from Frida trace

Tags: frida

Is there a way to kill/abort the thread/process from a hook (let's say the `onLeave` hook) in frida-trace?
If "yes", how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (rather ugly) solution to this is simply to crash the program by setting the thread's context's instruction pointer to unmapped memory or kernel memory. You can accomplish that with Frida's interceptor by using `this.context`:

```
onLeave: function (result) {
    this.context.pc = 0
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Well, yes, I guess I could do that. But then I'll end up with orphan memory that the OS won't be able to reclaim, right?

Comment: @alexandernst: usually all memory is freed by the OS after process termination